# Video encoding for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, video-encoding

Are there any 3rd party companies delivering video/audio encoding services for Windows Azure?
Amazon has e.g PandaStream.

/Rune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use Media Services in Azure: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/

Answer (score 0):

It is not a commercial 3rd party offering but evangelist Wade demonstrates how you can use Azure with Expression Encoder. Look here: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/using-expression-encoder-4-in-a-windows-azure-worker-role/